# lightning-record-form doesn't show fields from the page layout

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, create-records

I created an lwc component which has just the `<lightning-record-form></lightning-record-form>` and this component is used in the quick action to create a record. It works fine for the existing record types. However for a new record type which was recently introduced , it doesn't seem to have few fields in the record creation form, though those fields are added in the corresponding page layout. What could be the reason for the fields missing from the record creation form?

Comment: Check the user's permissions for these newly added fields.

Comment: User has access to these fields and these are not the new fields. Record type and page layout are new.

Comment: Is the record type mapped to the user as well?

Comment: Yes, same user can create record and have those fields available , when created through standard New button

Comment: Given the above comments, I'd think it is a caching issue. Has the user logged out completely and logged in again since this change? Have you tried turning off the persistent cache on the session settings (at least temporarily) to check if this is the issue?

Comment: Also, could you perhaps [edit] the question to add the code snippet of your component's HTML template so we can see how you are using the `lightning-record-form`?